# Why do my dependencies that I've installed in my virtual environment appear outside as well using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I've installed dependencies using `python3 -m pip...` in my virtual environment which I created with and activated by `python3 -m venv env && source env/bin/activate`, I've even checked if it was activated by `echo $VIRTUAL_ENV` which gave me `.../env` however when I do `python3 -m pip list` in my virtual environment and outside I get the same results. Why do my dependencies in my virtual environment show up outside?

Comment: this does not seem right, just to rule out:  are you sure that you have different installed packages between env(in your new env) and base(outside env)?

Comment: No I don't, I've installed Django in my virtual environment, but that shows up as a global dependency

Comment: `type -a python3` ?

Comment: Virtualenv and outside give the same result ```python3 is /usr/local/bin/python3
python3 is /usr/bin/python3```